# How to update only the text of a DIV and not any other child node

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id='container'>
  This is some text
  <span> more text </span>
</div>
```

How can I update only the text section ("This is some text") while not affecting the "span" ?

Comment: What are you trying to select it with?  JS?  jQuery?

Comment: Is this even valid?  Im not expert though so I have no idea, but to me the text should be in a tag of some sort, a div, p, span etc.

Comment: Could not think of any way, other than dirty hacks. Like, storing the child nodes, replacing the text and insert the child nodes again

Comment: Use a variable to render "This is some text".

Comment: have you tried my working solution ....

Comment: hi tryout my javascript solution its also working in jsfiddle you can check demo over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pure javascript solution**

## DEMO

```
 var fieldNameElement = document.getElementById('container');

fieldNameElement.removeChild(fieldNameElement.firstChild);
var newText = document.createTextNode("New Text");
fieldNameElement.insertBefore(newText , fieldNameElement.firstChild);
```

or

**Jquery**

## DEMO

```
$('#container').each(function(i,el) {
    el.firstChild.data = 'New Title Goes Here';
});
```

Comment: You need to change the title of the question then--since this is a very specific solution to a very specific problem. No sense junking up google with an inaccurately labeled question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var childNodes = elem.childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
    var child = childNodes[i];

    if (child.nodeName == "#text") {
      elem.removeChild(child);
      i--;
    }
}
```

Works in IE7 (that's what I got). You may need to adjust the nodeName check for different browsers, but the overall concept is the same: don't check for `firstChild`, check for the type of node by way of the `nodeName` property.

Answer (score 0):

it would be easiest to format it as such with a paragraph tag and use javascript to just change the innerHTML of the paragraph tag. That is the easiest and shortest way to change only that text.

```
<div id='container'>
<p id="text">This is some text</p>
<span> more text </span>
</div>
```